# ImageView Visibility Issue in Relative Layout

Tags: android, visibility, android-relativelayout

I've seen all sorts of code that makes me think that mine should work, but for some reason it does not. I've got an ImageView that animates vertically down another image and I want the mobile imageview to disappear once the animation is complete but it does not.  The 'scanbar' imageview is the one in question. it is set as invisible in the XML and is made visible on a button press. I need it to go away when the animation is finished.

```
public class scan extends Activity {

EditText Quote;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
ImageView scanbar;
public void scanLine()  {
    // Displays the scanline animation over the wireframe image


    ImageView wireframe;
    scanbar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scanbar);
    wireframe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wireframe);
    scanbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // Super ultra-secret code

}
Animation.AnimationListener scanListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scanbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setResults();
    }
};
```

The setResults(); call works properly, so I know that section of code is being executed.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using for your animation frames?

Comment: it's a translateanimation that moves an image from the top of the frame to the bottom

Answer (score 4):

Will give this old question an answer just in case someone stumbles upon it like me.

Check out stickupkid's answer here: [Android, setVisbility to gone not working in RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424371/android-setvisbility-to-gone-not-working-in-relativelayout). Call `clearAnimation()` on what ever view is doing the animation before calling `View.INVISIBLE`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that: Calling clearAnimation() on the view that is doing the animation before calling View.INVISIBLE, or GONE does the trick.