# Android, setVisbility to gone not working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am using a RelativeLayout to put a rotating spinner animation on top of a placeholder image while the real image is being loaded in a background thread.

When the real bitmap is ready, the code below is run with in the UI thread with Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)

The problem is, that all my attempts to hide the rotating image after the real image was loaded seem to fail. I got it working finally by bringing the underlying imageview to the front, but I'm just curious why setVisibility(View.GONE) and the other methods I tried are not working. I tried various methods trying to hide the rotating animation, but none of them worked.

The spinner image is declared simply in an ImageView as:

```
android:src="@drawable/spinner_black_20"
```

Then I start an rotation animation on it. Once the real image is loaded, this is where I try to hide it (in the UI thread as mentioned above)

```
View v = (View)imageView.getParent();
ImageView spinner = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);
if (spinner != null) {
    spinner.getAnimation().cancel(); // this works, the animation stops
    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // doesn't work, spinner bitmap still there
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE); // doesn't work
    spinner.getDrawable().setVisible(false, false); // tried this, no joy
    spinner.refreshDrawableState(); // thought this might help, nope
    spinner.invalidate(); // nor this
    imageView.bringToFront(); // this works, in that spinner disappears to background
}
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Are you logging or stepping through the debugger inside the if(spinner != null) block?  If have a bug in your retrieving your reference to spinner, this block doesn't execute.

Comment: Yeah, I stepped through it. And in fact two lines in that block do work when executed: The .cancel() call works, as does the imageView.bringToFront() call

Comment: Just a thought here...maybe the animation is blocking the calls to setVisibility.  Can you set an AnimationListener on the spinner's animation, and then hide it in the onAnimationEnd method?

Comment: This issue is also asked here, still no answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515470/imageview-visibility-issue-in-relative-layout

Answer (score 63):

Try calling `spinner.clearAnimation();` before the setVisibility.

Which is what Rich alluded to...

Comment: This fixed my very similar problem.

Comment: I also had the same issue, this fixed it for me!

Comment: Fixed my problemmm!! .. Thankkssss!!

Comment: @evaneus I think this is the correct answer. (Not a lame fix like postDelayed... Which causes more bugs then it fixes.)
Please accept it.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. I  lost an hour to this bug.

Comment: Holy batman, so glad I found this answer. I tried so many things, such as using invisible instead of gone and manually updating the alpha, when really I needed to clear the animation.

Comment: After a day of tries, your answer finally helped me. Thanks!