# Android - ProgressBar setVisibility to GONE not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar, android-spinner

I've been adding a `ProgressBar` to the fragments in my app. I've set it up to the two main fragments (used as tabs) as follows:

`ProgressBar` in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Setting `ProgressBar` `VISIBLE` and `GONE`:

```
spinner = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This works without any problems. I've tried to add another `ProgressBar` to another fragment which has a `WebView`:

`ProgressBar` in `fragment_article.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ArticleFragment$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webPage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Setting Visibility:

```
spinner = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Setting the visibility the same way as the previous code but for some reason this is not setting the `ProgressBar` to `GONE`. Not sure what's wrong.

I've tried using `clearAnimation` as suggested here [Android, setVisbility to gone not working in RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424371/android-setvisbility-to-gone-not-working-in-relativelayout) but still nothing.

```
spinner.clearAnimation();
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: try changing id to R.id.progressBar2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as @Illegal Argument's answer I was using `getActivity` instead of `viewInflated`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this code:

```
spinner = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

If you are using fragments it should be like this:

```
spinner = (ProgressBar)viewIinflated.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);//same case with dialogs
```

If you are using activity then:

```
spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

Comment: Yep that was it...in fact I tried just changing the id of the fragment's `ProgressBar` which ended up in an exception, which makes sense as I was getting the `Progressbar` from the `Activity` not the `Fragment`

Comment: @j.grima Initially I thought that too because spinner is a dropdown like component and you named your progressbar variable spinner. A quick check of your code made me realize that the instantiation was incorrect

Comment: @j.grima it doesn't matter if you call Activity.findViewById or View.findViewById, try both and see what those methods return,  if they return the same View (and they will if you use different ids) the result will always  be the same

Answer (score 6):

I had a same issue (progressBar.setVisibility() was not working).

As @Illegal Argument said,

```
// in Activity
ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

should be working, if that code runs on uiThread(mainThread).

My problem was that I was trying to run the code not on uiThread.
So I solved the issue by changing code from

```
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due the fact that `View.GONE` will prevent the `View` from being drawn to the screen, while another `View` `android:layout_align[POSITION]` component may be defined to that `View`, so their position can't be calculated.

`View.INVISIBLE` will work cause it just make it invisible, but the `View` is still there and other `View` can calculate their position if the align is set to it

Comment: Thanks, just realised I was getting the `ProgressBar` from the `Activity` not the `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score -1):

progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);