# Unable to hide ProgressBar on PostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am attempting to hide a `ProgressBar` after I load data from `Asynctask`, but the progressbar still persist even when I specify `View.GONE`.
I have went through different links but wasn't able to get desired results

I am specifying this on `onCreate` in my activiy I am specifying following code:

```
    layout =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLayout);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(DisplayActivity.this,null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

In my Asynctask `onPreExecute` event I am specifying following code:

```
    layout.addView(progressBar,params);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

`OnPostExecute` I am specifying following code:

```
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

I have almost tried everything from following links:

[Android - ProgressBar setVisibility to GONE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342875/android-progressbar-setvisibility-to-gone-not-working)

[Android, setVisbility to gone not working in RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424371/android-setvisbility-to-gone-not-working-in-relativelayout)

Comment: I tested your code works fine can you post your `AsyncTask class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will works for you.Try add progressbar onCreate method

layout.addView(progressBar,params);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Then onPreExecute just setVisibility

progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
and onPostExecute just hide ProgressBar

progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: It worked thanks!
putting this bit of code on onCreate method did the work
    layout.addView(progressBar,params); 
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this statement it in a UI thread

```
runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() { 
     public void run() {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
 }));
```